# WebStorm JSX nested component code format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formatting, webstorm, jsx

Hopefully I am not the only one person with this issue. Maybe I have wrong settings.

When I format the code like

```html
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route component={Root}>
        </Route>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

It becomes

```html
<Provider store={store}> <Router history={browserHistory}> <Route component={Root}>
        </Route> </Router>
</Provider>
```

I have tried to make code style for html add custom elements and set to insert new line before. But it does not change anything. While VS Code can do this without any problem, but VS Code does not have so good intellisense.

Hope someone can give some suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need to do is check the `Keep line breaks` option under `Preferences > Code Style > HTML` to prevent WebStorm to override those breaks you carefully inserted manually.